# How do I align a GridViewColumn Header?

Tags: wpf

The following aligns the columns below the Header:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Joined" Width="90">
  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding tabDateJoined}" TextAlignment="Left" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

How do I align a GridViewColumn Header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `GridViewColumn.Header` block:

```
<GridViewColumn>
  <GridViewColumn.Header>
    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Joined" Width="90" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"/>
  </GridViewColumn.Header>
  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding tabDateJoined}" TextAlignment="Left" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: I implemented a header template for my gridviewcolumn header and I wasn't being able to fit its width to the header's entire width. You guide me in the right direction. I solved by using <GridViewColumnHeader HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>